# Kotlin opening new fragment in nav drawer example

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation

I'm relatively new with Kotlin and I'm trying to extend the navigation drawer example by adding a button into my fragment that can open another fragment directly without having to select it from the navigation drawer.
Here is my button listener in my fragment's `onCreateView` function:

```
    addButton.setOnClickListener()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"ButtonPressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        this.activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mobile_navigation, R.layout.fragment2).commit()
    }
```

I'm not sure I completely understand how to approach this. The button works fine and calls the toast, but I can't get it to change the fragment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use Navigation Architecture components?

Comment: Not sure. Though the template has a mobile_navigation.xml file with a "navigation" element. I've figured out how to add new fragments into the navigation drawer, but I'm trying to change the current fragment through buttons and functions inside fragment class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the template has a mobile_navigation.xml file with a "navigation" element.

The [Navigation Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) is used by default in recent android studio versions, so the [`navController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController) is the responsible for fragment transaction instead of doing that manually by the `supportFragmentManager`

```
addButton.setOnClickListener() {
    Toast.makeText(this.context,"ButtonPressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val navHostFragment = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
        .primaryNavigationFragment as NavHostFragment

    navHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.layout.fragment2)
}
```

Also, make sure that `R.layout.fragment2` is the fragment id of the destination fragment in the `R.id.mobile_navigation.xml`